# Verify nth derivative satisfies differential equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been working my way through  an old series of maths books (An Analytical Calculus by Maxwell) and finally got stuck on a question midway through book 2 (of 4). If anyone could help that would be great (as there are quite a few like this following). The question is in two parts and I can get the first part. I figure that the first part is to be used in the solution of the second part (but could be wrong). We haven't covered ODEs yet, so any methods using theorems from ODEs shouldn't be used.

a) Prove that
$$
(x+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}~\left\{(x+1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}\right\}
=(n+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n\left\{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n\right\} 
$$
--> I can do this part.

b) Prove also that the function
$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}
$$
Satisfies the equation:
$$
(1-x^2)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^2y-(1+x)\left(\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right)+(n+1)^2y=0
$$ --> I can't do this part.

Worst case I thought I could do it via a recurrence relation between terms in a power series in the DE, and then check the function satisfies it, but it gets messy fast. I can't find any similar solved problems anywhere!

The first part is solved via Leibniz:
$$
(x+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}{(x+1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}}=\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^{n+1}}-(n+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n{(x+1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}}
=\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n(n+1){(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}+\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n(n+1){(x+1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}}-(n+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n{(x+1)^n(x-1)^{n+1}}=\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n(n+1){(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is this notation? When you write $(\frac {dy}{dx})^n$ do you mean $\frac {d^n y}{d x^n}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry, new to this site and Latex. (Actually the Maxwell books, which are quite old, use the same notation for n>2).

Comment: OK, I think I know how to do it. Substitute nth derivate into ODE and then use multiple Leibniz + chain rules. Part a) is an example of this technique. It's a lot of work and not quite working out but should be able to finish it tonight after work (and maintain my 100% record on the book problems :)). If anyone has a simpler technique, I would be very grateful to know it!

Comment: I have a couple thoughts but not much time to pursue them, maybe it can help.  One is that the symmetry $x\mapsto -x$ means there is another version of (a) that looks identical with $x-1$ and $x+1$ switched around.  This should give you more freedom to manipulate (b) so you can both raise or lower the number of derivatives when switching between the exponent $n+1$ being attached to $x-1$ versus $x+1$.

Comment: The other thought I had was that Leibniz may not really be making things simpler here.  $(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n$ is simply $(x^2-1)^n (x+1)$, whose binomial expansion looks pretty much as simple as Leibniz and is far more flexible with work with.

Comment: Yes, I used this when I tried the nth derivative of the series expansion of the expression you suggested and then trying to show the expansion satisfied the recurrence relation from the ODE. Got messy fast! –

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved via multiple Leibniz and chain rules. It's a long proof and easy to make mistakes. Here are the main parts of it.

First, using similar techniques to part a):
$$
(x+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}=\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}[(n+1)x+n-1].
$$
Then using Leibniz:
$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+2}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n(x-1)(x+1)}=(x^2-1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+2}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}+(n+2)2x\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}+(n+2)(n+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}
$$
Then

- Expand the LHS using the chain rule and then the chain rule again on each of the two outputs
- Expand the second term on the RHS using similar techniques to part a), and
- Leave the third term alone.

This gives:
$$
(1-x^2)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+2}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}-(x+1)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n+1}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n} = \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n}~{(x+1)^{n}(x-1)^{n-1}}[-(n+2)(n+1)(x-1)^2-2(n+1)(n+2)(x+1)(x-1)-n(n+1)(x+1)^2+2(n+2)(x+1)(x-1)+2(n+2)(n+1)x(x-1)+2(n+2)nx(x+1)-2(n+2)(n+1)(x+1)(x-1)+(n+2)(n+1)(x+1)(x-1)-(x+1)(x(n+1)+n-1)] 
$$

The above RHS rationalizes to:

$$
-(n+1)^2\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^{n}~{(x+1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}
$$

Hence the result. A very long proof (at least by the standards of the other questions in the book) to solve something that looks like it might not be too difficult to prove!.